# eclipse error while click on any project

Tags: eclipse

When I am using eclipse then it will pop up error like this (I am using kubuntu OS)

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.resources.VirtualComponent.clearCache()V
at  org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.componentcore.J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.clearCache(J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.java:469)
```

What would be the proper course of action to avoid that error message?

---

Full stack:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.resources.VirtualComponent.clearCache()V
at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.componentcore.J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.clearCache(J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.java:469)
at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.componentcore.J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.checkIfStillValid(J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.java:462)
at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.componentcore.J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.getCachedReference(J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.java:441)
at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.componentcore.J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.getReferences(J2EEModuleVirtualComponent.java:104)
at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.classpath.WebAppLibrariesContainer.computeReferences(WebAppLibrariesContainer.java:96)
at org.eclipse.jst.common.jdt.internal.classpath.FlexibleProjectContainer.computeClasspathEntries(FlexibleProjectContainer.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jst.common.jdt.internal.classpath.FlexibleProjectContainer.<init>(FlexibleProjectContainer.java:122)
at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.classpath.WebAppLibrariesContainer.<init>(WebAppLibrariesContainer.java:54)
at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.classpath.WebAppLibrariesContainerInitializer.initialize(WebAppLibrariesContainerInitializer.java:34)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeContainer(JavaModelManager.java:2642)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getClasspathContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1813)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainer(JavaCore.java:2652)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2578)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2679)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:1866)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.determineIfOnClasspath(JavaModelManager.java:996)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.create(JavaModelManager.java:892)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.create(JavaModelManager.java:822)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.create(JavaCore.java:2537)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.ResourceAdapterFactory.getAdapter(ResourceAdapterFactory.java:44)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.AdapterManager.getAdapter(AdapterManager.java:322)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.AdapterManager.loadAdapter(AdapterManager.java:352)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.LegacyResourceSupport.getAdapter(LegacyResourceSupport.java:622)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ObjectActionContributor.isApplicableTo(ObjectActionContributor.java:223)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ObjectContributorManager.isApplicableTo(ObjectContributorManager.java:303)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ObjectActionContributorManager.contributeObjectActions(ObjectActionContributorManager.java:83)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PopupMenuExtender.addObjectActions(PopupMenuExtender.java:262)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PopupMenuExtender.menuAboutToShow(PopupMenuExtender.java:339)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager.fireAboutToShow(MenuManager.java:338)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager.handleAboutToShow(MenuManager.java:469)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager.access$1(MenuManager.java:465)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager$2.menuShown(MenuManager.java:491)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:235)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1176)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1200)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1181)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu._setVisible(Menu.java:199)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runPopups(Display.java:3519)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3109)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2405)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2369)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
```

Answer (score 1):

This programmer blog post [simply reports](http://programmers-blog.com/2010/03/01/tomcat-in-eclipse-staring-problem):

> #### Problem:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.resources.VirtualComponent.clearCache()V
```

> #### Solution:
>
> run the eclipse updates - get the latest version and everything should work fine.

That means it would help to know what exact version of:

- eclipse
- WST
- JDK

you are running to see if an upgrade could help or not.